# 64 bit Firebreath NPAPI Plugin not registering in Windows

Tags: windows, plugins, 64-bit, npapi, firebreath

I have generated a test Plugin using prep2015x64.cmd.

`prep2015x64.cmd` contents are given below

```
echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set _FB_GEN="Visual Studio 14 Win64"
call "%~d0%~p0\common.cmd" %*
if %errorlevel% == 2 exit /b 1
call "%~d0%~p0\winprep.cmd"
```

The Plugin is completely generated, and to ensure it is 64 bit, I cross checked it with dumpbin /Headers and it gives that DLL is 64 bit

```
FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
               9 number of sections
        56DFCDF9 time date stamp Wed Mar  9 12:47:13 2016
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              F0 size of optional header
            2022 characteristics
                   Executable
                   Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses
                   DLL
```

Then, I try to register it, using an elevated Command Prompt in C:\Windows\SysWOW64.
I use the following command for registration

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe C:\workspace\firebreath\build\bin\TestPlugin\Release\TestPlugin.dll
```

It gives me an error:

```
   The Module "C:\workspace\firebreath\build\bin\TestPlugin\Release\TestPlugin.dll"
 may not be compatible with version of Windows that you are running. 
Check if the module is compatible with an X86(32-bit) or X64(64-bit) version of regsvr32.exe
```

I am using Windows 7, 64 Bit Operating System, so I am really confused as to what is going wrong here. Is it the plugin generation or something else.
Is there any alternate way to get the Plugin registered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to get it working. I used Visual Studio 2008.

1. Generated the plugin using fbgen.py
2. Run the prep2008x64.cmd. Build files and vcproj gets generated in this step.
3. Open Plugin.vcproj file in any editor and replace /machine:X86 with /machine:X64
4. Open vcproj and then add "Additional Library Dependencies" with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\amd64". This is required for ATL Libraries.
5. I was not sure of whether it gets linked with 32 bit libraries or 64 bit libraries. So, I explicitly added "Additional Dependencies" in Linker Input with the following below list

   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\x64\Kernel32.lib"
   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\x64\User32.lib"
   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\x64\Gdi32.lib"
   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\x64\WinSpool.lib"
   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\x64\Shell32.lib"
   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\x64\Ole32.lib"
   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\x64\OleAut32.lib"
   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\x64\Uuid.lib"
   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\x64\ComDlg32.lib"
   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\x64\AdvAPI32.lib"
   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\x64\Psapi.lib"
   "....\ActiveXCore\Debug\ActiveXCore.lib"
   "....\PluginCore\Debug\PluginCore.lib"
   "PluginAuto\Debug\PPL_PluginAuto.lib"
   "....\NpapiCore\Debug\NpapiCore.lib"
   "....\ScriptingCore\Debug\ScriptingCore.lib"
   "....\boost\libs\thread\Debug\boost_thread.lib"
   "....\boost\libs\system\Debug\boost_system.lib"
   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\x64\WinInet.lib"
6. Changed the "Target Machine" in Linker Advanced from "Not Set" to "MachineX64(/MACHINE:X64)"
7. Built the Plugin
8. Registered the plugin using normal cmd prompt (NOT elevated cmd prompt) and normal regsvr32.exe (NOT specific like C:\Windows\SysWOW64) 
   C:\Users\Username>regsvr32.exe npPlugin.dll
9. Tried with Firefox 64 bit version 44.0.2, but it did not work. I thought it was problem with plugin. But no, I later downloaded ChromiumPortable_43.0.2357.18.paf.exe (64 Bit) from  https://sourceforge.net/projects/crportable/files/ . Chromium version below 44 only support npapi plugins.
10. Install the Chromium Portable and enabled npapi plugins in chrome://flags and later launched FBControl.htm. Finally it worked.....!!!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is that you're using the 32 bit version of regsvr32; syswow64 stands for "system Windows on Windows 64", in other words it's the 32 bit windows on windows 64 bit.  You actually (ironically enough) want to use the `c:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe` file.

To be safe, just use the one that is in the path instead of specifying a specific one and you'll always get the right one (unless the computer's configuration was messed up).  The 64 bit version will automatically chain to the 32 bit version if it's a 32 bit DLL, but the 32 bit version will just not work if it's a 64 bit dll.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already tried using regsvr32.exe on normal cmd prompt directly but still I got the same error. Is there anything I have to check or configure in firebreath to get it working properly, because building plugin for 32 bit works completely fine. Only 64 bit plugin has a problem..

Comment: I'm not having any trouble, but I haven't built with vs2015, so I don't know.  if it's saying that the module may not be compatible then that sounds like a compiler issue, so I don't think it's directly related to the firebreath code.  if anything it could be something cmake isn't setting up correctly

Comment: Thanks again for your response... I tried something new now. I built 64 bit firebreath plugin with prep2008x64.cmd and then built firebreath plugin with Visual Studio 2008. Now I am able to register the plugin with normal regsvr32 from cmd prompt. But when I launch FBControl.htm on Mozilla Firefox(64 bit), I get "A Plugin is needed to Display this content". I am unable to figure out, what might be the problem now....

Comment: Since this obviously requires troubleshooting, I'd strongly recommend asking in the firebreath-dev google group rather than here -- it's not a cut and dried question.

Comment: Thanks Taxilian for your help.. I have posted the steps I had followed to make it work...

Comment: You might try figuring out a way to fix it in cmake